# Jquery Mobile - select displayed value resfresh with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I spent several hours to try to figure out unsuccesfully this problem.

I have a select in my page and an query aimed to update the selected value and the value displayed.

The value displayed is never updated. When I click on the select, the value is properly.

Here is my code :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">

<fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
     <label for="device1">device1 Roma home</label>
     <select name="device1" id="device1"  >
          <option value="Roma">Roma</option>
          <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
          <option value="London">London</option>
          <option value="Madrid">Madrid</option>
          <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
     </select>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){

   some code here...

   PUBNUB_demo.subscribe({
         channel: 'datavenueGeolocator',
         message: function(m){
          $( "#device1" ).val(m['device1']);  
         }
     });

   });


</script>
```

m['device1'] contains for example "Paris"

I tried plenty fo things ... menuselect, refresh... without success.

Thank in advance for your help.
Aure

Answer (score 0):

After setting the new value, you need to tell jQM to refresh the selectmenu widget:

```
$( "#device1" ).val((m['device1']).selectmenu("refresh");
```

http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh